# Spring Boot Upload BootRepackage Executable Jar

Tags: java, maven, gradle, jar, spring-boot

I am using Spring-Boot to develop my new project. In my build.gradle file, I am using 'bootRepackage.classifier', so I can separately generate the default jar of my project and the executable jar that is generated using Spring Boot. I would like to publish both jars, but I am running into issues. I am using the uploadArchives task to upload my jars to a Nexus Maven repository. I can only get my default jar to upload. Here is the part of my build.gradle file that pertains to uploading the archive:

```
bootRepackage.classifier = 'exec'

jar {
    baseName='default'
    version = '1.0.0'
}

uploadArchives {
    repositories {
       mavenDeployer {
             repository(url: "repositoryURL") {
                 authentication(userName: "username", password: "password")
             }   
             pom.groupId = 'groupId'    
             pom.version = "1.0.0"  
       }
    }
}
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: what are the issues

Comment: My issue is that only my default jar will upload. I am not sure how to upload my executable jar that is created when I use the bootRepackage.classifier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a couple solutions elsewhere on SO:

[Publishing a spring boot executable jar artifact](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28833849/publishing-a-spring-boot-executable-jar-artifact):

```
artifact(file("$buildDir/$project.name-$project.version-${bootRepackage.classifier}.jar")) {
    classifier 'exec'
}
```

[Gradle maven-publish does not build standalone spring-boot application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26212237/gradle-maven-publish-does-not-build-standalone-spring-boot-application):

```
publish {
    dependsOn assemble
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I found that I was using uploadArchives when I could be using the publishing task. With this change, I used your first solution and it did exactly what I wanted.

Comment: Didn't work for me: 

Could not find method artifact() for arguments [/var/workspace/build/my-project-unspecified-null.jar, build_b8ejm5oe5e1nrnc8xnmcspqxz$_run_closure3@4227f732] on root project 'my-project' of type org.gradle.api.Project.